# Can somebody help me to get started with Google Dialogflow in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-cx

Searched a lot but there is no precise answer on how to get started with dialogflow in spring boot.

**Aim**: To detect intent from GDF knowledgebase and return back the response.

**What I have done so far:**

Tried executing this code https://github.com/googleapis/java-dialogflow/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/dialogflow/DetectIntentTexts.java
by creating a main app.

**App.java**

```
package com.example.dialogflow;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DetectIntentTexts theDetectIntentTexts = new DetectIntentTexts();

        String projectId = "abc";
        String sessionId = "xyz";
        String lang = "en";

        List<String> myTexts = new ArrayList<>();
        myTexts.add("hi");

        String ans = null;
        try {
            ans = String.valueOf(theDetectIntentTexts.detectIntentTexts(projectId, myTexts, sessionId, lang));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Bot reply:" + ans);

    }

   

}
```

But it fails to run.

I have my service account GCP set in local machine and `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your-project-credentials.json` is set too

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It fails to run. What's your error?

Comment: `java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ListKnowledgeBasesResponse
  location: class com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.KnowledgeBasesSettings
`


And it redirects me to KnowledgeBasesSettings.java

Comment: What are you imports?

Comment: It's the same maven dependencies mentioned here  https://github.com/googleapis/java-dialogflow/tree/61351f83a3e169105fa136b36cb22919aa84c273/samples/snippets . No modifications done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to solve it.
Steps:

First run

```
gcloud auth application-default revoke
```

This will remove user account & service account credentials.

Now login into gcloud using service account credentials.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json
```

Wonder why we have to revoke user account credentials because keeping both the accounts and activating service account didn't work.

Now it works.